# Can the following quantity be simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\theta = 2 \arcsin\left(a \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{M}\right)\right)$$

where $0 < a < 1 $ and $M$ is a positive integer.  Can $\theta$ be expressed in a further compact form? If possible in a form without any trigonometric function?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: The original quantity was $$\theta = \arccos(1-2a^2sin^2(pi/M) )$$. I could reduce it to the expression written in the question.